# Match function error when condition is "text()" function

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am working on automating some values in Google sheets. In this specific case I want to find the first instance of a month name within a column.

Since the MATCH function is supposed to adapt automatically over time, the match_condition is: `text(today()-30,"MMMM")`

The whole function then looks like this:

```
MATCH("text(today()-30,"MMMM")",C5:C121,0)
```

What I have tried so far:

- loosing the `" "` before and after the match_condition
- calculating the match_condition in a different column and then getting the text()-values from that column: `MATCH("X1",C5:C121,0)` - and again addling and loosing `" "`

The error I get is: "Formula parse error"

Does anybody have an idea what could work?

Comment: Certainly you do *not* want the double quotations around the `TEXT()` function, nor the `X1`. If that doesn't solve the issue, is it possible that your locale requires the use of semi-colons rather than commas as argument separators?

Answer (score 0):

With a date in say G1 of the month of interest, and in G5 copied down to G121 `=MONTH(C5)` then the result you want might be achieved with, in C1:

```
=INDEX(C5:C121,MATCH(MONTH(G1),G5:G124,0))
```